# Qusetion in Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I solved this questios :
1-Define (override) the toString method to print person name, age, and his/her list of friends’ names.
2-Define a method that returns the number of friends of a person. 
3-Define a getter method that returns the friends of a person as an Array.
4-Define a non-static method that returns the oldest friend of a person. 
5-Define a non-static method to return the average age of friends.
6-Define a method compareTo which takes a person Object p as parameter to compare the age of p with the age of this object. (i.e., returns a value >0, =0, or <0 based on the comparison)

**this is second part of question that I didn't understand it** 
1-Define a non-static method addFriend to add a friend to a person. Note that:
A person can be added on only once in the friend list. Hint: use the equals method to check whether the person that we want to add has been already added in the list 
A person cannot be a friend of himself. Hint: use the equals method to check whether the person that we want to add is the same as the person
2-Define the non-static  method isFriend to see if a given person is a friend of this object.
3-Define a static method commonFriends that takes 2 person objects as parameters and returns the common friends of these two persons in an ArrayList.

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Person1 {

    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    private ArrayList<Person1>Friends=new ArrayList();

   public String getName(){
    return Name;
}
     public String toString(){
         String st="";
         String x="";
     st= Name+","+Age;

     for(int i=0;i<Friends.size();i++)


     x+=Friends.get(0).getName();
     return st+","+x;
    }
     public int getFriends(){
         return Friends.size();

}
     public Person1 OldestFriends(){
         int maxIndex=0;
         for(int i=0;i<Friends.size();i++){
             if(Friends.get(maxIndex).getAge())
                    maxIndex++;
         }
       return  Friends.get(maxIndex);
     }

    public int compareTo(Person1 p) {

         return (this.Age)-(p.Age); 


    }
    public boolean equals(Person1 p) {
        Person1 P= new Person1();
        if(this.Name==P.Name&&Age == P.Age ){
       // return ( Name.equals(P.name) && Age == P.Age );
                 //both objects have same Name
                 return true;
             } else {
                 //both objects have different Name
                 return false;
             }

    }
    public void addFriend(){
       Friends = new ArrayList<Person1>();

    }


    }
```

Comment: Tag as Java please....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly . To begin with , try something like this :

```
public void addFriend(Person1 person){

   if(!this.equals(person) && !Friends.contains(person)) {
       Friends.add(person);
   }

}

public boolean isFriend(Person1 person){
    return Friends.contains(person);
}

public static List<Person1> commonFriends(Person1 person1,Person1 person2){
     List<Person1> commonFriends = new ArrayList<Person1>(person2.getFriends());
     return commonFriends.retainAll(person1.getFriends());
}
```

And please follow [Java naming conventions.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: return commonFriends.retainAll(person1.getFriends());

Comment: this method its not working so i changed to this return commonFriends;